# Google Maps API Geodecoder Limit

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps-api-3, geocode, google-geocoder

I've made a trip planner for bus and I had an idea. Instead of doing the request from a PHP page using AJAX when someone click on the map to setup the marker, I created a script using the method geocoder from Google Maps API in Javascript.

Now, since I know Google limit the request per day per "IP" at 2,500 I want to know something.

Since the request is made by Javascript (client script) directly to the Google server's. My website will use the limit of 2 500 because the request come from a script on my website or it's going to be 2 500 requests per client I get (by IP in reality) because the request come from the client side ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP Address used is the servers, not the clients. If you plan on it exceeding 25,000 a day, than you can signup through Google's paid services, and they will charge for anything exceeding the limit.

Answer (score 0):

Your web site can access 25,000 map loads per day so (an example) if you have 5,000 visitors then each can access 5 map loads and then you will hit your limit.

Found [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usagelimits) in the google maps api documentation.

Your idea of the definition of a map load is specifically addressed [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_mapload) in the documentation:

> A single map load occurs when:
>
> a map is displayed using the Maps JavaScript API (V2 or V3) when loaded by a web page or application;

Therefore, the server's IP address is used.

Comment: Yes, but my question was, when the script send a request to the Google Server (Javascript, occur on client side), which IP is used ? Mine or the one of the visitor since the script is executed from the client side.

Comment: The Server's IP address is used.